# Nothing similar and a not-so-frequent Apps Script question

Tags: google-apps-script

Through trial and error I modified the below line of code to print the range `B4:I59`. Can someone help me to understand what the code says and/or how do I read it?

Original code

```
var printRange = '&c1=0' + '&r1=0' + '&c2=7' + '&r2='+row2; // B2:APn
```

Modified Code

```
var printRange = '&c1=1' + '&r1=2' + '&c2=9' + '&r2='+row2; // B4:I59
```

This is my whole code:

```
//* Print Extentions
function printPdf() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var pdfOpts = '&size=A4&fzr=false&landscape=false&fith=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
  var row2 = 59;
  var printRange = '&c1=1' + '&r1=2' + '&c2=9' + '&r2='+row2; // B4:I59
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(200).setHeight(50);
  app.setTitle('Print Extentions List');
  var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_new');
  app.add(link);
  ss.show(app);
}
```

The code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;
```

You are defining a URL that will allow you to export the given spreadsheet as a PDF using the specified options. The `&` symbols separate arguments you are passing into the URL.

[This document](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) gives a nice description of the parameters you are using. According to that document:

```
//r1=Start Row number - 1        row 1 would be 0 , row 15 wold be 14
//c1=Start Column number - 1     column 1 would be 0, column 8 would be 7   
//r2=End Row number
//c2=End Column number
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that answered my question